# vuejs set data value for v2.2.5

Tags: laravel, http, request, vue.js, axios

So here's my code

```
var portal = new Vue({
el: "#AnnounceController",
data: {
    ann: {
        id: '',
        content: ''
    },
    announces: [],
    success: false,
    edit: false
},
methods: {

    fetchAnnounce: function () {
        axios.get('/api/announces')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.announces = response.data;
                console.log(this.announces);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
},
computed: {},

mounted: function () {
    console.log('mounted')
    this.fetchAnnounce()
}
```

I have a GET request via axios to a laravel based api, when I look at the response from axios I do see my data, when I try to assign that data to the 'announces' from data, it doesn't work. Vue-devtools shows my data 'announces' attribute as empty, and the log for this.announces shows me my data, somehow like the data attribute for the vue instance and the this.announces are different.

Comment: dumb fix, the this referred to axios, so I just added a self=this and used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetchAnnounce: function () {
    axios.get('/api/announces')
        .then(function (response) {
            this.announces = response.data;
            console.log(this.announces);
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```